# Beyond Mac Address: Uniquely Identifying Devices on the Server Side

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on an analytics tool. I would like to be able to reasonably identify unique users (or more likely, unique machines) -- some degree of inaccuracy is okay. I need to support both low-level devices (Android/iOS) and web (JS/Flash), because I'm building the clients in Haxe. (The other caveat of this is that I can't use language-specific APIs.)

Previously, I used the tuple of `(ip, mac address)` to uniquely identify users. However, in Flash (and Javascript), you don't have access to the mac address. It occurred to me that I should store and manage identity on the server side, perhaps with a GUID. The client would request a GUID (or some sort of ID) from the server, and use that for any subsequent requests from the same device.

However, I'm not sure if a GUID is a good idea; or if I should supplement it with the IP or other information. (I do have access to get the IP from the client side.)

The workflow on the client would be:

- Check for a stored unique identifier
- If it exists, send it with all requests
- If it doesn't, make a call to request a unique identifier and store it
- Send the unique identifier with all subsequent calls

Of course, this would only be unique per device, and there may be some way to get a false positive of two users by removing the identifier on the local device.

On the server side, it would be as simple as generating a new GUID and sending it to the user when they request a unique identifier.

Is this a good approach? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the level of uniqueness and security you need you might consider using [persistent cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie). The cookie could be the *unique identifier* you described in your workflow. And to ensure that the cookie will be sent over subsequent requests it should be a [persistent cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Persistent_cookie).

Comment: +1 This looks promising. It doesn't address *what* to store though.

Comment: What do you want to store? You emit a persistent cookie and then the browser takes care of storing it on the client computer. You will emit this cookie if it is not present in the request meaning that the client is unknown or doesn't have the cookie stored yet. You should set the `Expires` property of this cookie when setting it to a reasonably far in the future date to ensure that it will be sent by the client on all subsequent requests for this duration. And since the cookie is persistent even when the client closes the browser it will be stored.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an SNMP agent on the device (most devices will support SNMP) then you can query the mac address(es) via SNMP and thus identify the device. This is how network management tools work (and tie together multiple interfaces to identify a single device with multiple interfaces)

Comment: You can't do this in Flash or Javascript, can you?